# In C#, how would I add diagonals to my A Star path finding class?

Tags: c#, path-finding, a-star

I have a simple path finding class using A*, however it only covers the four cardinal directions in a tile map. It obeys walls and avoids them, but in open spaces it creates a zig-zag pattern to get to it's destination.

I'd like to simplify that pattern to include diagonals - in open areas of the map, but so far if I use diagonals, it seems to ignore the walls entirely.

How can I solve this and correctly add the diagonals?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class AStar {

    private List<Node> openList;
    private List<Node> closeList;
    private List<Node> neighbors;
    private List<Node> finalPath;

    private Node start;
    private Node end;

    public AStar()
    {
        openList = new List<Node>();
        closeList = new List<Node>();
        neighbors = new List<Node>();
        finalPath = new List<Node>();

    }

    public void FindPath(MazeCell startCell, MazeCell goalCell)
    {
        start = new Node(0, 0, 0, null, startCell);
        end = new Node(0, 0, 0, null, goalCell);

        openList.Add(start);

        bool keepSearching = true;
        bool pathExists = true;

        while(keepSearching && pathExists)
        {
            Node currentNode = ExtractBestNodeFromOpenList();

            if (currentNode == null)
            {
                pathExists = false;
                break;
            }

            closeList.Add(currentNode);

            if (NodeIsGoal(currentNode))
            {
                keepSearching = false;
            } else
            {
                FindValidFourNeighbors(currentNode);
            }

            foreach(Node neighbor in neighbors)
            {
                if (FindInList(neighbor, closeList) != null)
                    continue;

                Node inOpenList = FindInList(neighbor, openList);
                if (inOpenList == null)
                {
                    openList.Add(neighbor);
                } else
                {
                    if (neighbor.G < inOpenList.G)
                    {
                        inOpenList.G = neighbor.G;
                        inOpenList.F = inOpenList.G + inOpenList.H;
                        inOpenList.parent = currentNode;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        if (pathExists)
        {
            Node n = FindInList(end, closeList);
            while (n != null)
            {
                finalPath.Add(n);
                n = n.parent;
            }
        }

    }

    public bool ContainsCoordinates(IntVector2 coordinate)
    {
        return coordinate.x >= 0 && coordinate.x < GameConfig.mazeSize && coordinate.z >= 0 && coordinate.z < GameConfig.mazeSize;
    }

    private void FindValidFourNeighbors(Node node)
    {
        neighbors.Clear();

        // Check South of this Cell //

        int south = node.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z - 1;
        IntVector2 SouthNeighbor = new IntVector2(node.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x , south);

        int north = node.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z + 1;
        IntVector2 NorthNeighbor = new IntVector2(node.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x, north);

        int east = node.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x + 1;
        IntVector2 EastNeighbor = new IntVector2(east, node.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z);

        int west = node.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x - 1;
        IntVector2 WestNeighbor = new IntVector2(west, node.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z);

        IntVector2 SouthEastNeighbor = new IntVector2(south, east);

        IntVector2 SouthWestNeighbor = new IntVector2(south, west);

        IntVector2 NorthEastNeighbor = new IntVector2(north, east);

        IntVector2 NorthWestNeighbor = new IntVector2(north, west);

        if (ContainsCoordinates(SouthNeighbor))
        {
            if (Maze.Instance.cellStorage[SouthNeighbor.x, SouthNeighbor.z].IsWalkable)
            {
                MazeCell c = Maze.Instance.cellStorage[SouthNeighbor.x, SouthNeighbor.z];

                if (!(c.cellEdges[(int)MazeDirection.North] is MazeCellWall))
                {
                    Node vn = PrepareNewNode(node, 0, -1);
                    neighbors.Add(vn);
                }
            }
        }


        if (ContainsCoordinates(NorthNeighbor))
        {
            if (Maze.Instance.cellStorage[NorthNeighbor.x, NorthNeighbor.z].IsWalkable)
            {
                MazeCell c = Maze.Instance.cellStorage[NorthNeighbor.x, NorthNeighbor.z];

                if (!(c.cellEdges[(int)MazeDirection.South] is MazeCellWall))
                {
                    Node vn = PrepareNewNode(node, 0, 1);
                    neighbors.Add(vn);
                }
            }
        }

        if (ContainsCoordinates(WestNeighbor))
        {
            if (Maze.Instance.cellStorage[WestNeighbor.x, WestNeighbor.z].IsWalkable)
            {
                MazeCell c = Maze.Instance.cellStorage[WestNeighbor.x, WestNeighbor.z];

                if (!(c.cellEdges[(int)MazeDirection.East] is MazeCellWall))
                {
                    Node vn = PrepareNewNode(node, -1, 0);
                    neighbors.Add(vn);
                }
            }
        }

        if (ContainsCoordinates(EastNeighbor))
        {
            if (Maze.Instance.cellStorage[EastNeighbor.x, EastNeighbor.z].IsWalkable)
            {
                MazeCell c = Maze.Instance.cellStorage[EastNeighbor.x, EastNeighbor.z];

                if (!(c.cellEdges[(int)MazeDirection.West] is MazeCellWall))
                {
                    Node vn = PrepareNewNode(node, 1, 0);
                    neighbors.Add(vn);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private float Heuristic(Node n)
    {
        return Mathf.Sqrt((n.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x - end.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x) * (n.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x - end.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x) + (n.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z - end.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z) * (n.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z - end.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z));
    }

    private float MovementCost(Node a, Node b)
    {
        return Maze.Instance.cellStorage[b.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x, b.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z].movementCost();
    }

    private Node PrepareNewNode(Node n, int x, int z)
    {
        IntVector2 iv = new IntVector2(n.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x + x, n.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z + z);
        Node node = new Node(0, 0, 0, n, Maze.Instance.cellStorage[iv.x, iv.z]);
        node.G = n.G + MovementCost(n, node);
        node.H = Heuristic(node);
        node.F = node.G + node.H;
        node.parent = n;
        return node;
    }

    public List<MazeCell> CellsFromPath()
    {
        List<MazeCell> path = new List<MazeCell>();
        foreach (Node n in finalPath)
        {
            path.Add(n.cell);
        }

        if (path.Count != 0)
        {
            path.Reverse();
            path.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        return path;
    }

    public List<int> PointsFromPath()
    {
        List<int> points = new List<int>();
        foreach (Node n in finalPath)
        {
            points.Add(n.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x);
            points.Add(n.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z);
        }
        return points;
    }

    bool NodeIsGoal(Node node)
    {
        return ((node.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x == end.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x) && (node.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z == end.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z));
    }

    Node FindInList(Node n, List<Node> xl)
    {
        foreach (Node nn in xl)
        {
            if ((nn.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x == n.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.x) && (nn.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z == n.cell.mazeCellCoordinates.z))
                return nn;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Node ExtractBestNodeFromOpenList()
    {
        float minF = float.MaxValue;
        Node bestNode = null;

        foreach(Node n in openList)
        {
            if (n.F < minF)
            {
                minF = n.F;
                bestNode = n;
            }
        }

        if (bestNode != null)
        openList.Remove(bestNode);
        return bestNode;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an A* before with diagonals and you just need to include them in the list of viable neighbors.

Technically you should do the costing/exclusion in your heuristic function rather, but just looking at your code surely you could just add 4 more checks in `private void FindValidFourNeighbors(Node node)`:

```
if (ContainsCoordinates(SouthEastNeighbor))
    {
        if (Maze.Instance.cellStorage[SouthEastNeighbor.x, SouthEastNeighbor.z].IsWalkable)
        {
            MazeCell c = Maze.Instance.cellStorage[SouthEastNeighbor.x, SouthEastNeighbor.z];

            if (!(c.cellEdges[(int)MazeDirection.South] is MazeCellWall) && !(c.cellEdges[(int)MazeDirection.East] is MazeCellWall))
            {
                Node vn = PrepareNewNode(node, 0, -1);
                neighbors.Add(vn);
            }
        }
    }
```

(Not too clear what the 'cellEdges' check is doing exactly but I assume you would need to check both sides for the diagonal and this is maybe where you are failing.)

Comment: cellEdges is checking for the presence of walls in the map, and disqualifying the next move if it finds one.

Comment: Unfortunately this is more or less the same solution I tried at first. It might be the heuristic code.

Comment: Yeah it could be anywhere actually, the code is fairly complex and hard to tell what is going on from just reading it. I would suggest a refactor to separate out the path-finding and costing components, keeping a pure A* pathfinder from your implementation code, then implement the costing and checks in the heuristic. You could check out this implementation too, it has diagonals: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/designtechniques/article.php/c12527/AStar-A-Implementation-in-C-Path-Finding-PathFinder.htm